# which function can i use instead of parseJSON  jquery version 1.3.2

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi i am using `jquery version 1.3.2`  , i use it because my jquery validation plugin does not work properly with `jquery 1.6.2` , but when using `version 1.3.2`

```
parseJSON is not a function
```

appears in firebug . i searched and found the answer that is because

```
parseJSON was added in version 1.4.1
```

so what function can i use instead of `parseJSON`

please help...................

Comment: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `JSON.Parse()`.

```
var jsontext = '{"firstname":"Jesper","surname":"Aaberg","phone":["555-0100","555-0120"]}';
var contact = JSON.parse(jsontext);
var fullname = contact.surname + ", " + contact.firstname;
```

Comment: It should be JSON.parse().

Answer (score 1):

You can always eval() JSON http://www.json.org/js.html
Or use one of the existing js libraries to parse JSON. This, for example: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js (Yoshi first :-) )

Answer (score 1):

You could add one yourself:

```
jQuery.parseJSON = function(json) {
  if(JSON && typeof JSON.parse === 'function') return JSON.parse(json);
  else return eval('(' + json + ')');
};
```

this will check if there is native JSON support and use that when available, else it will use the eval method (see also [here](http://www.json.org/js.html))

Answer (score 0):

Try This ,,

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

```
  <script>
  function myFunction() {
   var obj = JSON.parse('{ "name":"mohsen", "age":26}').myChartZ("myChart3");
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML.jsonfile = obj.name + ", " + obj.age ;

}
```